# How to pass tags with space

Tags: azure-cli, powershell-core

I'm trying to add multiple tags through a variable using Azure-CLI (using Powershell Core).

`az resource tag  --tags ${tagsToAdd} --id $resource.id`

Where `$tagsToAdd="a=b c=d"`

But this gives me only one tag :

```
"tags": {
    "a": "b c=d"
    }
```

What is wrong with this? Using `az resource tag  --tags a=b c=d --id $resource.id` correctly produces two tags.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use it as below.

```
$tagsToAdd=@("a=b","c=d")
az resource tag --tags ${tagsToAdd} --id $resource.id
```

[image]

Comment: Never though I could use an array to pass those parameters looking at the documentation. Thanks!

Comment: Great answer. Just want to highlight this works also where the tag's name or the tag's value have spaces. Other solutions tend to trip where the name or the value has a space in it.